# Data service created by angularjs factory doesn't get dependencies

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope

I am trying to wire up a simple data service to retrieve data from the server for http calls. I am using TypeScript to write the code.  For some reason I can't get the service to see its dependencies. 
Here is the service the way it is generated by Typescript

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.constant('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:63342');

//This follows the pattern created by Typescript
var myService = function(){
    function myService($http, baseUrl){
        this.$http = $http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.http = typeof this.$http;
        this.url = typeof this.baseUrl;
    }
    myService.$inject = ['$http', 'baseUrl'];
    return myService
}

app.factory('myService', [
    '$http', 'baseUrl',
    myService
]);

app.controller('myCtrl',
        ['$scope', 'myService',
            function($scope, myService){
                $scope.httpType = myService.http;
                $scope.urlType = myService.url}]
);
```

When I run the code locally the p tags get the ng-bind attributes set on them.  But, of course, they have nothing in them.  When I break on the $scope assignments, myService is available and it has the $inject variable, but none of the other 4 variables.  The available examples for Typescript and angular are pretty thin.  There must be something really basic I am doing wrong.

[Here is a fiddle with the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/pthalacker/mK27V/) I don't know why the fiddle doesn't transclude the scope variables.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in :

```
var myService = function(){
    function myService($http, baseUrl){
        this.$http = $http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.http = typeof this.$http;
        this.url = typeof this.baseUrl;
    }
    myService.$inject = ['$http', 'baseUrl'];
    return myService
}

app.factory('myService', [
    '$http', 'baseUrl',
    myService
]);
```

Angular will call `myService` with arguments `$http,baseUrl` which `myService` does not accept. So you need to do :

```
var myService = function($http, baseUrl){
            this.$http = $http;
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
            this.http = typeof this.$http;
            this.url = typeof this.baseUrl;
}
myService.$inject = ['$http', 'baseUrl'];
```

Alternatively if you want to use TypeScript classes use the same pattern I recommend for Controllers : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1 and use `service` instead of `factory`

Comment: myService accepts the arguements in the inner function not the outer one.  This is the code that TypeScript generates.  It is the same as MainController in your video. I don't see in that video where you register the controller with the app.  Almost every example I have seen of creating a backend data service uses factory to create it, so I have been following those examples.

Comment: @pthalacker I've created a video to demonstrate the recommended pattern for services : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1 + github https://github.com/basarat/video-angularjs-typescript-services

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work following a module pattern to expose your service's properties, as well as using the inline notation to declare the service.  Check out the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tVajIshcCegIwywGWL9Y?p=preview.  Code pasted below for the script:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.constant('baseUrl', 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/news?api_key=FILDTEOIK2HBORODV&id=7digital-US:artist:304&format=json');


app.factory('myService', ['$http', 'baseUrl', function($http,baseUrl){
        var http = typeof $http;
        var url = typeof baseUrl;
        return {
          http: http,
          url : url
        };
    }]);

app.controller('myCtrl',
               ['$scope', 'myService', 
               function($scope, myService){
               $scope.httpType = myService.http;
               $scope.urlType = myService.url;
               }]              
              );
```

Comment: Also disregard the other url used there and re-substitute your own baseurl.

Comment: I have now created 3 examples from scratch to figure out where I am going wrong and in two of them, the service is now getting its dependencies, but the controller is not get its dependency on the service, so I will probably now post that code and see what I get back.